# Что означает переменная перед ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Много раз видел вот такой запрос `$J.ajax( { } );` И очень хочу узнать, что же значит (делает) переменная J ?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего эта переменная используется вместо `$` чтобы избежать конфликта с другими фреймворками (или с jQuery другой версии). Поищите где-то в коде строку вида

```
$J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Если найдете, значит моя догадка верна.

Comment: Это оно и есть, но совсем не обязательно использовать noConflict. Может быть просто некий jq-плагин в своем неймспейсе переименовал $ в $J, кому-то так удобнее.